# How can you use a setup method in ActionMailer Previews?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I would like to avoid duplicating the setup for multiple mailer previews. What is the best way to clean this up?

```
class MyMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def email1
    setup
    mailer.email1
  end

  def email2
    setup
    mailer.email2
  end

  def email3
    setup
    mailer.email3
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe you can call it at `initialize` method

Comment: @Tom I updated my answer for a couple solutions that could work with your previews.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two possible solutions I found:

There is something called `preview_interceptors` that are used when generating mailer previews, you could add your own like this:

`config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.preview_interceptors = :my_setup
```

`test/mailers/previews/my_setup.rb`

```
class MySetup                                                                                         
  def self.previewing_email(message)                                                                   
    message.subject = "New subject"                                                                                             
  end                                                                                                  
end
```

`test/mailers/previews/user_mailer_preview.rb`

```
class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview 
  include ActionMailer::Previews
  register_preview_interceptor :my_setup

  def welcome_email                                                                                    
    UserMailer.with(user: User.first).welcome_email                                                    
  end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
end
```

The message parameter is an instance of `ActionMailer::Parameterized::MessageDelivery`, I am not sure everything you can do with it, but you can set some attributes on the email itself.

I couldn't find much documentation on preview interceptors, but here is a [link](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/66cabeda2c46c582d19738e1318be8d59584cc5b/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L367) to how they are used in Rails.

```
  # Previews can also be intercepted in a similar manner as deliveries can be by registering
  # a preview interceptor that has a <tt>previewing_email</tt> method:
  #
  #   class CssInlineStyler
  #     def self.previewing_email(message)
  #       # inline CSS styles
  #     end
  #   end
  #
  #   config.action_mailer.preview_interceptors :css_inline_styler
  #
  # Note that interceptors need to be registered both with <tt>register_interceptor</tt>
  # and <tt>register_preview_interceptor</tt> if they should operate on both sending and
  # previewing emails.
```

I tried to include Rails `before_action` in the class, but it wouldn't hook the methods in the previewer, so the second option I found is to build your own `before_action` like this:

```
module MySetup                                                                                      
  def before_action(*names)                                                                         
    UserMailer.instance_methods(false).each do |method|                                             
      alias_method "old_#{method}", method                                                          

      define_method method do                                                                       
        names.each do |name|                                                                        
          send(name)                                                                                
        end                                                                                         

        send("old_#{method}")                                                                       
      end                                                                                           
    end                                                                                             
  end                                                                                               
end    

class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview 
  extend MySetup

  def welcome_email                                                                                 
    UserMailer.with(user: User.first).welcome_email                                                 
  end 

  before_action :setup

  private

  def setup
    puts "Setting up"
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm asking about the mailer preview, not the mailer itself.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, missed that it was a `Preview`

Comment: I'm afraid that interceptor doesn't run until AFTER the mail is actually rendered?

Comment: It's hard to know how useful it is without knowing what exactly you are trying to do, but it does hit the `previewing_email` method before it actually renders in the browser.  You can modify different attributes of the email itself before it renders in the browser.  I was able to change the subject of the email for example, and see my modified subject in the browser.

If that isn't enough, then I supposed you'd have to create your own `before_action` or just keep with the way you are currently doing it.

Comment: Unless you can figure out how to use the Rails built in `before_action` in your previewer, and if you do I'd appreciate if you share how you did it :D

Comment: In my case, the setup method is instantiating the objects to pass to the mailer so it has to happen before the ActionMailer method is called. I'm not sure how often people run into this?

Comment: Not sure, we honestly don't even use rails mailers in our apps.  We are using litmus.com right now to build emails.  I would probably just use a service object to instantiate my objects and pass them to the mailer and be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

### Use an `initialize` method.

Just override the parent `initialize` method, call `super` and then run your setup:

```rb
class MyMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview

  def initialize( params = {} )
    super( params )

    @email_address = "jules@verne.com"
  end

  def email1
    mailer.email1( @email_address )
  end

end
```

You can view the `ActionMailer::Preview.new` method [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionMailer/Preview.html#method-c-new) as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of what you're asking maybe you could add it into one single method that takes the mailer method as a param

```
class MyMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def email_for(emailx) # (Pass the method(email1, etc) as an argument where you're calling it
    setup
    mailer.send(emailx.to_sym) # Call the method param as a method on the mailer
  end
end
```

Would that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

you can extend [Rails::MailersController](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/railties/lib/rails/mailers_controller.rb)

```rb
# config/initializers/mailer_preview_setup.rb

class Rails::MailersController
  before_action :setup, only: [:preview, :download]

  private

  def setup
    # your code here
  end
end
```

or `prepend` to overwrite

```rb
# config/initializers/mailer_preview_setup.rb
module MailerPreviewSetup
  def preview
    setup
    super
  end

  private

  def setup
    # your code here
  end
end

Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  Rails::MailersController.prepend MailerPreviewSetup
end
```